# Проверка существования значения колонки в SQLite для добавления несуществующего

Tags: android, sqlite, if

Помогите пожалуйста. Есть База данных, которая имеет несколько столбцов, заполняемая, скажем, из формы №1. А есть еще форма №2, которая считывает из Базы данных один единственный столбец, который использует для своих нужд.

Как сделать, чтобы в случае отсутствия в БД введенного в поле значения столбца предлагалось создать новое значение, а если это значение имеется, то приложение не разрешало создавать дубликат?

Comment: почитайте это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927394/sqlite-create-table-with-unique-combination-of-columns

Answer (score 1):

В SQLite есть выражение PRAGMA, которое возвращает курсор, в которой в каждой строке описано каждое поле из таблицы.

```
PRAGMA table_info(table-name);
```

Почитать: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info